# Changing Jekyll site structure

Tags: jekyll

In my site settings, I have the default

```
baseurl: ""
```

My site is a blog and my domain name already includes the word `blog` (blog.example.com), but when I add posts to my site they end up with the path `/blog/yyyy-mm-dd/title-here`.

How can I get them to be put in `/yyyy-mm-dd/title-here` instead (without the initial `/blog` path)?

I am using GitHub pages to serve my site, so I cannot use `mod_rewrite`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `baseurl`setting is not relevant for this.

Adding `permalink: :year/:month/:day/:title` to `_config.yml` gives the desired permalink style.